# Create a Function That Returns Year of Max Precipitation Value for hourly record for over the years?

Tags: python, pandas

Create a Function That Returns Year of Max Precipitation Value:

In the cell below, complete the code needed for a function called calc_max_precip_year that will subset a Pandas DataFrame and identify the row where a particular column (in this case HPCP) has a max value. The function should return the YEAR associated with the row that has the max value. Year should be of type integer.

The function should:

Take a pandas dataframe and a column name (as a text string) as an input
Return a year in a numeric form.
Then run the function to create the following 3 variables:

calculated_year_hourly
calculated_year_daily
calculated_year_monthly

_____________My code is but not working:

```
def calc_max_precip_year(df, col_name):
    """
    Functcalc_max_precip_year(df, col_name)ion that takes a dataframe and calculates the year during which 
    a max event occurred.
    # Add the parameters and returns elements here to fill out your docstring
    """
    # Populate this function with the correct code
    max_row = df[df.Points == df.Points.max()]
    print(max_row)

    year = max_row.index.year    
    #print(year)

    return year


max_year = calc_max_precip_year(precip_hourly, 'HPCP')   

max_year
```

Thank you.

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Points'.

Comment: Try `max_row = df[df["Points"] == df["Points"].max()]`

Answer (score 0):

Lets break down what your function needs to do first.

- takes an input dataframe and a column name
- finds the max value in that column
- returns the year when that max value occurs

So now the first thing you want to in your function is find the index of the max value in the input column. Then you use that index to get the year. you can do that in the following manner -

```
def calc_max_precip_year(df, col_name):
    max_index =  df[col_name].idxmax(axis=1, skipna = True)
    max_year = df.iloc[max_index]['year']
    return max_year
```

Those three lines should get you the year where `col_name` has a max value. (You may need to rename what the year column is here as I have assumed it is simply `'year'`)

Comment: Thank you very much Karan.  This is little complicated for me. I am trying to go in different way - posted bellow, still some small issue.